# Google Docs API v1 - how to create list nested element?

Tags: google-docs-api

So there is this example: https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/lists

How do I make nested list element? So how would look example adding `Sub-Item One`?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: Sorry for late notice. Generally I would agree with your answer but that is quite naive way which is correct when you have exactly this document and you do not have any other text in document. I will post more generic solution in second.

Comment: Thank you for replying and letting me know about it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I deeply apologize my answer was not useful for your situation. I could know that my answer was not suitable for your question. So I have to delete my answer, because I don't want to confuse other users. I apologize for my poor skill. I would like to study more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for version 1 of Google Docs API it's pretty complicated. Best way I found is to divide process of document creation in two phases:

1. put indented text altogether with named ranges
2. style named ranges

Between first and second phase document is being refreshed on client side and named ranges got recalculated to positions. Thanks to this design I'm able to get it all done. Important trick is in phase 1 send all requests in reversed order as advised in tutorials.

Phase 1 requests would look more or less like this:

```
requests.add(
            new Request()
                    .setCreateNamedRange(
                            new CreateNamedRangeRequest()
                                    .setName(rangeName)
                                    .setRange(
                                            new Range()
                                                    .setStartIndex(1)
                                                    .setEndIndex(outputText.length() + 1))));
    requests.add(
            new Request()
                    .setInsertText(
                            new InsertTextRequest()
                                    .setText(outputText)
                                    .setLocation(new Location().setIndex(1))));
```

Notice that named range request is being create before inserting text. After preparation of all requests be the end of phase 1 and after they get reversed, named ranges requests are being correctly applied to just inserted piece of text.

Another important thing is `rangeName` parameter. For single line types of text (title, headers, etc.) I don't care much and I name them html-ish (title, h1, h2, p). Fore multi line pieces (like bullet list from question) it's important to name each multi line section with unique name. So if I have 3 lists in my document each line in each of lists will be created with `rangeName = "l" + x` so each line in list 1 would have named range named `l1`, each line in list 2 would have named range named `l2` and so on.

Then phase 2 comes. For single line ranges:

```
List<MyRange> myRanges = GoogleContentCreator.countSingleRanges(document, rangeName);
    if (myRanges != null) {
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MyRange myRange : myRanges) {
            requests.add(new Request().setUpdateParagraphStyle(new UpdateParagraphStyleRequest()
                    .setRange(new Range()
                            .setStartIndex(myRange.getStart())
                            .setEndIndex(myRange.getEnd()))
                    .setParagraphStyle(new ParagraphStyle()
                            .setNamedStyleType(namedStyleType))
                    .setFields("namedStyleType")
            ));
        }
        return requests;
    }
```

and for multi line ranges (here bullet list explicitly):

```
MyRange range = GoogleContentCreator.countListRange(document, rangeName);
    if (range != null) {
        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        requests.add(new Request().setCreateParagraphBullets(
                new CreateParagraphBulletsRequest()
                        .setRange(new Range()
                                .setStartIndex(range.getStart())
                                .setEndIndex(range.getEnd()))
                        .setBulletPreset("BULLET_DISC_CIRCLE_SQUARE")));
        return requests;
    }
```

Crucial thing are `countSingleRanges(...)` and `countListRange(...)` methods. I'm not pasting implementation because it's quite messy but core concept is that `countListRange(...)` returns one range which takes start of first occurrence of `rangeName` tag and end of last occurrence of `rangeName` tag. On the other hand `countSingleRanges(...)` returns list of ranges exactly as they were placed in document.

After all this operations document gets correctly formatted and styled.

One thing I wasn't able to get to work in Google Docs API so far are tables but that was not scope of this question anyway.